# Artin Algebra Representation Chapter Resource Request

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

I am working through chapter 10 of Artin's Algebra 2ed which introduces Group Representations. However, I've found that the approach to introducing groups is unlike the usual method used by more extensive though introductory treatment of the subject. For instance, rings and algebras are not introduced by this point. Furthermore, as is normal with this text, the exercises are quite challenging. For other chapters this is not an issue since I can use exercises with solutions available from other texts to study.

I am wondering if anyone knows of any resources that can well supplement this chapter. I am in search of resources with more examples, and with exercises that have solutions. My main issue is not having problems that I can work through and then check for correctness.

Thank You

Comment: Etingof's text (http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf) builds up the general theory quite nicely, in a perhaps more (mathematically) motivated manner.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a nice resource for further study though perhaps more appropriate after I've worked through the theory of rings and fields. My main concern is not having practice problems with available solutions. For instance, I enjoy the exposition in Artin, though I often worked through Dummit and Foote problems before attacking those in Artin. It takes me some time to build intuition.